# Kahler condition related to Ricci curvature formula of a Hermitian, holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds

I read a local formula like this:
Under some sort of Kahler condition,
$$Ric(h)=-i\partial\bar\partial \log \det(h_{\alpha\bar\beta})$$

where $h_{\alpha\bar\beta}$ is the matrix of the Hermitian metric $H$ on a local trivialization of a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ over a complex manifold $M$. If $E$ is the holomorphic tangent bundle, then $Ric(h)$ is the Ricci curvature of the manifold $M$ with Hermitian metric $H$, and we know this formula works if $M$ is Kahler. My question is:

What is the exact expression of Kahler condition here if we replace $T^{(1,0)}M$ by a general Hermitian and holomorphic bundle $E$?